# First day in calendar datetimepicker

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, momentjs, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I'm using [Bootstrap Date/Time Picker](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker)

**How can I set the first day of the week as Monday?**

I have this code:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="date" placeholder="Enter date">

$("#date").datetimepicker({format: "DD/MM/YYYY"});
```

Comment: Show us what you did so far ?

Comment: you have to change your locale
see the documentation here : http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#locale

Answer (score 3):

Set locale before calling datetime picker.

```
moment.locale('en', {
      week: { dow: 1 } 
    });

   $('#date').datetimepicker();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/97e4tskL/

Comment: check my jsfiddle.
you need to include  moment-with-locales.js in you scripts.

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment-with-locales.js